# what is the difference between $(($RANDOM % 10 +1)) and $(( ( RANDOM % 10 ) + 1 ))

Tags: linux, bash

So I'm trying to create a random number limit the range from 1 to 10. There is a slightly different syntax between the two and I don't know if there any difference between those.

`$(($RANDOM % 10 +1))`

I tried this and it's working fine.

`$(( ( RANDOM % 10 ) + 1 ))`. Including an extra () between `RANDOM % 10` and `+1` seems to work the same as the code above. But it has only one $ instead of 2.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nothing. `%` has higher precedence (the same as `*`) than `+`, so the unparenthesized version is equivalent to the explicitly parenthesized one.

---

I originally missed that the second one also used `RANDOM` instead of `$RANDOM`. In an arithmetic context, a string is treated as an identifier, and is (recursively) expanded until you get an integer. If at any point the string is not a defined parameter, the value `0` is used instead.  For example:

```
$ foo=bar
$ bar=6
$ echo $((bar))
6
$ echo $((foo))
6
```

In the last case, `$foo` expands to `bar`, which expands to 6.

IMO, it's better to use the explicit expansion. If the parameter isn't set due to a typo, you'll get an explicit error

```
$ foo=6
$ echo $((10 + $fo))
bash: 10 + : syntax error: operand expected (error token is "+ ")
```

rather than a silent "success" that might not be intended

```
$ echo $((10 + fo))
10  # ?? Why not 16?
```

Comment: Also you don't need `$` before variable names inside `$(())`

Comment: OTOH, `x='1+1'; echo $((2*$x))` is 3, while `$((2*x))` is 4

Comment: @thatotherguy That's arguably a bug, although I'd have to check the POSIX spec to see if it's even defined. `dash` does what I would vote to do with `$((2*x))` in this case, which is complain that `1+1` is an illegal number.

Comment: The POSIX spec just says that `$((x))` and `$(($x))` have to return the same thing. It doesn't seem to say whether the expansion of `x` needs to be treated as a discrete subexpression or not (i.e., implicitly parenthesized or not). `$((2*$x))` is, to me, more predictable, since the shell expands `$x` before the arithmetic expression is evaluated.